# Any Java Program has at least two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

Any Java program, there are at least two threads running at the same time. What are these?

Comment: Thread one and thread two? :-)

Comment: Why not take a thread dump with `jstack` and find out?

Comment: @paxdiablo - I think you are confusing threads and bananas.  :-)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananas_in_Pyjamas#Premises

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt there are only 2 threads but may be you are referring to the main thread and the garbage collector. Inspect with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

On graphical applications, that's true. At a bare minimum, you have your main thread and the AWT incident thread.

I'm not certain it's true for *all* Java programs, especially simple console-based ones. In certain Java *implementations,* the garbage collector itself may be a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Nope!. Every java program at least one thread.

Comment: Perhaps the reference is to threads running on a particular VM family.